# phpwkhtmltopdf - Could not create PDF - Failed without error message

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

Trying to create PDFs using PHP and the package [phpwkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

// You can pass a filename, a HTML string or an URL to the constructor
$pdf = new Pdf('http://www.google.co.uk');

// On some systems you may have to set the binary path.
//$pdf->binary = 'C:\pdf';

$pdf->send('google.pdf');
if (!$pdf->send()) {
    throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
}
```

However get the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not create PDF: Failed without error message: wkhtmltopdf "http://google.com" "C:\Windows\Temp\tmp4047.tmp.pdf"' in C:\wamp\www\site\ajax\createpdf.php on line 24
```

[image]

Went to c:\windows\temp and can see file tmp4047.tmp.pdf - but is corrupt and wont load

Have run wkhtmltopdf from command line with no issues - PDF is created ok

```
 wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

EDIT - used [snappy](https://github.com/KnpLabs/snappy) instead - works fine, has anyone got this working on AWS elastic beanstalk? any tutorials? TQ

```
//snappy
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;
$snappy = new Pdf('C://"Program Files"/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe');
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
echo $snappy->getOutput('http://www.google.co.uk');
```

NOTE - windows users put quotes round "Program Files"

Comment: Probably a permissions issue. Try catching that exception and printing a stack trace, then go through wkhtmltopdf's sources using the trace and see exactly where it crashes.

Comment: Hi - sure you were right, but tried different package as quicker

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem running on Windows and Apache with same error message, I fixed the issue just a few moments ago, by using `'bypass_shell' => 'true';` on the commandOptions and also specifying the binary path pointing to your installed wkhtmltopdf folder, normally in Program Files.

Working code:

```php
$pdf = new Pdf([
                  'commandOptions' => [
                  'useExec' => false,
                  'escapeArgs' => false,
                  'procOptions' => array(
                  // This will bypass the cmd.exe which seems to be recommended on Windows
                  'bypass_shell' => true,
                 // Also worth a try if you get unexplainable errors
                  'suppress_errors' => true,
               ),
               ],
               ]);
               $globalOptions = array(
               'no-outline', // Make Chrome not complain
              // Default page options
               'page-size' => 'Letter'
                );

               $pdf->setOptions($globalOptions);
               $pdf->addPage('http://www.google.com');
               $pdf->binary = 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe';
               if (!$pdf->send()) {
            throw new Exception('Could not create PDF: '.$pdf->getError());
          }
```

If you set the useExec command parameter to true, then in your binary path you should add double quotes to "Program Files" or you will get the error C:\Program is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file .. Credits to Mikehaertl for his helpful documentation and amazing work with wkhtmltopdf. Cheers!